# Alamofire response is allways nil

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I'm trying to code a basic example of a REST client using Alamofire 4 and swift 3, but whatever the service I try to access, the response is allways nil.

A'm I missing any configuration?

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
    }
}
```

Podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'RESTClient' do

  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for RESTClient
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.2'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'

end
```

Info.plist

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQsNt.png)

Comment: I think it is necessary to include the request method type in the constructor

Comment: In Alamofire 4 it's not necessary. This code I've copied exactly as it is at https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as Alamofire uses asynchronous requests, the next part of the code was being executed before the requisition.

So, to assure the order of execution, the code that depends of the response must be into the closure.

Comment: What do you mean by clousre